# Serializing and deserializing Joda DateTime object

Tags: java, xml, datetime, serialization, jodatime

I've started migrating a project from using Java Standard Date to Joda DateTime.

My project uses XML serialization to save the objects to a XML file. In this particular case, I have an Item class which has a DateTime attribute.

At some point, I'm initializating the object, including the DateTime attribute like this:

```
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setIdSearchCriteria(this.searchCriteria.getId());
        item.setUrl(fullUrl);
        item.setTitle(itemTitle);   
        item.setDateTime(new DateTime());
```

I use XMLEncoder to serialize the item using an auxiliar class:

```
public void saveDataList(List<Serializable> dataList) throws DAOGenericException 
{
    if(dataList == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    checkDirectory();
    ArrayList<Serializable> writtenObject = (ArrayList<Serializable>) dataList;
    FileOutputStream os;
    try {

        // Save data as xml file
        os = new FileOutputStream(new File(fullFilename));
        XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(os);
        encoder.writeObject(writtenObject);
        encoder.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        throw new DAOGenericException(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
}
```

And apparently, the DateTime is being saved at the xml... but with no value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.7.0_21" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="java.util.ArrayList">
  <void method="add">
   <object class="com.pikes.domain.Item">
    <void property="dateTime">
     <object class="org.joda.time.DateTime"/>
    </void>
    <void property="id">
     <int>1</int>
    </void>
    <void property="idSearchCriteria">
     <int>1</int>
    </void>
    <void property="title">
     <string>A title</string>
    </void>
    <void property="url">
     <string>http://www.random-url.com</string>
    </void>
   </object>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```

Apparently, it is saving nothing, but no, it is just saving the "actual" DateTime. By that I mean that if I save the Item in the XML file at, for example, 15:30, and then, I load the XML file at 18:00, then the date shows... 18:00!!

Of course that is not the behaviour I was expecting. I was expecting to save the milliseconds at the XML file so whenever I deserialize the object I get the same DateTime everytime.

What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried the following, getting the same result:

```
item.setDateTime(DateTime.now());
item.setDateTime(Instant.now().toDateTime());
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a `java.beans.PersistenceDelegate` implementation for Jodatime and set it as a persistence delegate for the respective type on your `java.beans.XMLEncoder` using `setPersistenceDelegate` method.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because DateTime does not have any properties (i.e. getXXX / setXXX) so XMLEncoder won't find anything to serialize.

You could wrap a DateTime in another type that handles serialization/deserialization, for example something like this...

```
public class DateTimeHolder {
    private DateTime dateTime;

    // Use this to create one of these holders
    public static DateTimeHolder holderFor(DateTime dateTime) {
        DateTimeHolder h = new DateTimeHolder();
        h.dateTime = dateTime;
        return h;
    }

    // Use this to get the actual date time value
    public DateTime dateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }


    // PROPERTIES...

    public String getTime() {
        // Format the date time as a string
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        // Parse the string into a date time and set the field
    }
}
```

If you want more control over your XML, you are better off using a more advanced framework like JAXB. (I've never actually used an XMLEncoder before...)

Hope this helps